# How to retrieve certificate and signature from app bundle in osx?

Tags: objective-c, macos, security, sign

I would like to know how to read an app bundles signature and the certificate which comes with the signature. I have been using the codesign tool so far. However I would like to retrieve these information in a more programatic manner. In the man pages is written that the codesign tool is just a shell wrapper of the codes signing api. The Code Signing Guide in the apple developer library says that the signature itself is stored in the binary file. Now my question is how do I get these information from the binary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160288/check-signature-of-osx-bundle-before-load?rq=1) and the Security Transforms Programming Guide I am able to solve this problem.